# Google Chrome Dev Tools Console Inconsistent

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

When I console.log DOM elements, the format output is inconsistent.

**For example (app.js):**

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box")[0];


console.log(boxes);
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]);
```

Google Chrome Dev Tools Console outputs:
[Image of Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcK5B.png)

But sometimes it will output:

[Image of Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do0CN.png)

I thought that everytime it would output the DOM elements not objects. (The HTML format)

Comment: The output depends on whether devtools was open at the time console.log was called.

Comment: @wOxxOm why would that matter?

Comment: Because devtools can provide much better rendering of objects when it intercepts them live at the cost of considerable overhead.